# Live table edit and update using ajax problem

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a table that is retrieving data from database, it has edit button at each row.

When I click "edit" button it makes that row editable and the text of button changes from "edit" to "save".

Till that point I have done it.
Now I want to send that edited row data to my `update.php` file using ajax or post method so I can update my db.

Bellow is my code:

```
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "<tr>
    <td>" . $row["Id"]. "</td> 
    <td>" . $row["Receiving"] . "</td> 
    <td>". $row["Date"]. "</td> 
    <td>" . $row["Department"]. "</td>  
    <td>" . $row["D_type"]. "</td> 
    <td>" . $row["Org"]. "</td> 
     <td>" . $row["Org_type"]. "</td> 
  <td>" . $row["File_No"]. "</td> 
  <td>" . $row["Subject"]. "</td> 
  <td>" . $row["File_Name"]. "</td> 
    <td>" . $row["Status"]. "</td> 
  <td> <a class='btn btn-primary' href='MarkReceived.php?id=".$row["Id"]."'>Mark Received</a> </td>
  <td> <a class='btn btn-primary' href='Delete.php?id=".$row["Id"]."'>Delete</a> </td> 
    <td> <button type='button' class = 'editbtn' id=".$row["Id"]." >Edit</button> </td> 
</tr>";
}
```

**jquery code:**

```
$('.editbtn').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').filter(function() {
        return $(this).find('.editbtn').length === 0;
    });
    if ($this.html() === 'Edit') {
        $this.html('Save');
        tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
    } else {
        $this.html('Edit');
        tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you have a problem with sending your data to the PHP page? Or do you want to know how to send the data to the PHP page?. The last question has been answered multiple times, and you should be able to find some information if you google.

Comment: @Umairarshad..simply you can do like when you click on save after edit,just send that data to the file you want,using this keyword you can send the the row data which is clicked on save,this is just a way how to do this

Comment: Are you having problems on how to use ajax?

Answer (score 0):

As much i have understand from your question,you are trying to send data on click of save using ajax,so you can do something like this

```
$(".save").click(function(){  
          $.ajax({
              async: true,
                url : "Your URL",
                method : "POST",
                data : {
                     Id: currentlyEditId,
                     Receiving: currentlyEditReceiving,
                     Date:currentlyEditDate // and so on

                     },  
            });
```

You can send data using ajax like this

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.editbtn').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').filter(function() {
      return $(this).find('.editbtn').length === 0;
  });
  if ($this.html() === 'Edit') {
      $this.html('Save');
      tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
  } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'update.php',
        data: {//your data}
      }).success(function (data) {
         // request success, do what you want to do here
      }).error(function () {
         // request error
      });
      $this.html('Edit');
      tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
  }
});
```

You can do it like this. or you can just change the id of the button if it's edit or save to have a cleaner code and it will separate two different actions. then just use this ajax

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.editbtn').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').filter(function() {
      return $(this).find('.editbtn').length === 0;
  });
  if ($this.html() === 'Edit') {
      $this.html('Save');
      tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
  } else {
      $this.html('Updating..');
      $this.attr('disabled', true);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'update.php',
        data: {//your data}
      }).success(function (data) {
        $this.attr('disabled', false);
        $this.html('Edit');
            tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
         // request success, do what you want to do here
      }).error(function () {
         // request error
      });

  }
```